# Word for something that is a perfect replacement of another

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a single word (or phrase) to point to something that is a perfect replacement of another.

e.g.

> This tool is a (perfect replacement/ **?**) of a recently produced one.

**Update:**

The new tool in fact is an alternative to the previously produced (and there are some essential differences between them). So, it is more efficient and specifically eliminated drawbacks of older product. Moreover,it is not necessarily made by the same manufacturer.

Comment: perfect seems the perfect adjective to me. No other word describes perfection quite so perfectly.

Comment: How can I express in zero words "why stop at one, zero is clearly better"?

Comment: Do you mean it is identical in appearance? Identical in every single aspect and component? Functionally equivalent? Better than the original?

Comment: why don't you say that it is an ***improvement*** of recent produced one?

Comment: @SamuelVimes thinking along the same lines. How about a "*superior*" version

Comment: [*Perfect substitute*](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/substitute.asp) is used in marketing.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question as currently posed, but if you mean an improved version, the word you are looking for is **upgrade**.  *"The Toolmaster Mark II is an upgrade to the Toolmaster Mark I."*

Comment: @Crosscounter, yes I think that your suggestion would also work, and Chris Sunami's upgrade is also a good one, in my opinion

Comment: @SamuelVimes,  Since the new tool in fact is an alternative to the previously produced (and there are some essential differences), I think _improvement_ cannot be the word.

Comment: @Eilia that kind of information must go right into the question, and right from the start, rather than getting buried in a comment a day later.  It is in your own best interest.

Comment: Because of that, and also because "perfect replacement" *is* a phrase that means "perfect replacement", I have to put this question on hold as unclear.

Comment: @RegDwigнt This question is clear to me.

Comment: Is the "new improved" tool made by a **different** manufacturer? This information is important to know and specify in your question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, it is not necessarily made by the same manufacturer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, The question has been updated.

Comment: Seems like the question will remain closed. [You can ask at meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/) to reopen the question, explaining the reason why "a perfect replacement" does not fit your need. I suspect that this is the biggest stumbling block.

Answer (score 2):

**Perfect Substitute**

[SubjectMoney.org](http://www.subjectmoney.com/definitiondisplay.php?word=A%20Perfect%20Substitute):

> A *Perfect Substitute* is a good that functions just the same as the
>   good it is being compared to. An example would be Coke or Pepsi, BP
>   petroleum or Exxon petroleum etc

[EconomicsHelp.org](http://www.economicshelp.org/blog/glossary/substitute-goods/):

> Two goods are *perfect substitutes* if the utility consumers get from
>   one good is the same as another. For example, a dollar from one FOREX
>   company, is worth exactly the same as getting a dollar from a
>   different FOREX company.
>
> A4 paper from Office World, gives same utility as A4 paper from
>   WHSmiths.
>
> Therefore, in theory, if one good was more expensive, there would be
>   no demand as people would buy the cheaper alternative

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_good):

> The degree to which a good has a
>   *perfect substitute* depends on how specifically the good is defined.
>   Take for example, the demand for Rice Krispies cereal, which is a very
>   narrowly defined good as compared to the demand for cereal generally.

Answer (score 1):

Is what you are looking for perhaps ***"[equivalent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equivalent)"***?

> Equal in value, amount, function, meaning, etc.
>
> one unit is equivalent to one glass of wine

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equivalent

Answer (score -1):

**supersede:** to take the place of *usu.* with improvement
*'Computer is a superseder of typewriter'*